# How to properly center this labels to start from left and other elements stay next to each other?

Tags: html, css, flexbox, responsive-design

How do I align the labels correctly so that they start from the left, and the other elements stay on top of each other?

What I have so far – in the picture, you can see the output – is not correct. I am still learning CSS.

```html
<div class="opening-hours">
  <div>
    <label style="font-size: 18px; margin-right: 20px;">Pondělí</label>
    <input class="toggle" type="checkbox" id="monday-open" name="open" class="js-toggle" style="display:inline-block; padding-top: 5px; margin-right: 20px;" />
    <label for="times" style="font-size: 18px; margin-right: 2%;">Od</label>
    <select name="timepicker" id="monday-from" class="timepicker" style="margin-right: 2%;"></select>
    <label for="times" style="font-size: 18px; margin-right: 2%;">Do</label>
    <select name="timepicker" id="monday-from" class="timepicker" style="margin-right: 2%;"></select>
  </div>
  <div style="display:block"></div>
  <div>
    <label style="font-size: 18px; margin-right: 20px;">Úterý</label>
    <input class="toggle" type="checkbox" id="tuesday-open" name="open" class="js-toggle" style="display:inline-block; padding-top: 5px; margin-right: 20px;" />
    <label for="times" style="font-size: 18px; margin-right: 2%;">Od</label>
    <select name="timepicker" id="tuesday-from" class="timepicker" style="margin-right: 2%;"></select>
    <label for="times" style="font-size: 18px; margin-right: 2%;">Do</label>
    <select name="timepicker" id="tuesday-to" class="timepicker" style="margin-right: 2%;"></select>
  </div>
</div>
```

[image: What it looks like now]

Result what i want to:

[image]

Comment: "*...center the labels correctly so that they start from the left, and the other elements stay on top each other*" - can you show an adjusted image to give an example of what you mean? How should the labels be "centered" *and* "start from the left"? What other element(s) should be "on top [of] each other"? Also `<div class="opening-hoenter image description hereurs">`, I think your class-name became incorrect when pasting your code? You also have invalid HTML due to repeated `id` properties in your HTML, as well as multiple `class` attributes (you can only have one, or one will be overriden)

Comment: A not so recommended approach now a days, but will work is to use HTML table.
Better to use divs, so search google on how to use divs to achieve what you need. There are advances concepts of CSS with Column based layouts as well.

Comment: Sorry for the incorrect specification of the question, i hope with the added image of result what i expect it will be more clear now. @DavidThomas

Comment: Can the HTML be changed at all, or is it required to be as shown? Incidentally, you'll be a happier developer if you keep your CSS outside of your HTML.

Comment: @DavidThomas sure it can be changed. :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One approach is as follows, using CSS Grid layout:

```css
/* generic CSS reset, so some of the browser defaults
   are overridden to maximise consistency across browsers: */

*,
 ::before,
 ::after {
  box-sizing: border-box;
  font: normal 1rem / 1.5 sans-serif;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}


/* moving the CSS out of the HTML, in order that all common CSS can
   be easily updated in one place: */

.opening-hours {
  font-size: 18px;
}

.opening-hours>div {
  /* Using CSS Grid layout: */
  display: grid;
  /* defining gaps between adjacent rows to be 1em
     and the gaps between adjacent cells in columns
     to be 0.5em (this is for left-to-right, top-to-bottom
     languages): */
  gap: 1em 0.5em;
  /* we create three columns, each column taking one
     fractional unit of the available space: */
  grid-template-columns: repeat(3, 1fr);
  /* 1em margin above and below the element, and
     auto margins either side in order to horizontally
     center the element within its parent: */
  margin: 1em auto;
  padding: 0.5em;
  /* allowing the width to vary from 30em (minimum) to 90vw
     (viewport-width units, maximum) with a preferred size of
     900px within the minimum and maximum constraints: */
  width: clamp(30em, 900px, 90vw);
}


/* just to help visualise the layout: */

label {
  border: 1px solid #000;
  border-radius: 0.5em;
  padding: 0.5em;
}


/* to ensure visibility of the :focus indicator should the client
   be using keyboard navigation: */

:focus-visible {
  outline-width: 2px;
  outline-style: solid;
  outline-color: #f90;
  outline-offset: 0.1em;
}
```

```html
<div class="opening-hours">
  <div>
    <label for="monday-open">Pondělí
      <input type="checkbox" id="monday-open" name="open">
    </label>
    <label>Od
      <select name="timepicker" id="monday-from" class="timepicker"><option>00:00</option><option>00:15</option><option>00:30</option><option>00:45</option><option>01:00</option><option>01:15</option><option>01:30</option><option>01:45</option><option>02:00</option><option>02:15</option><option>02:30</option><option>02:45</option><option>03:00</option><option>03:15</option><option>03:30</option><option>03:45</option><option>04:00</option><option>04:15</option><option>04:30</option><option>04:45</option><option>05:00</option><option>05:15</option><option>05:30</option><option>05:45</option><option>06:00</option><option>06:15</option><option>06:30</option><option>06:45</option><option>07:00</option><option>07:15</option><option>07:30</option><option>07:45</option><option>08:00</option><option>08:15</option><option>08:30</option><option>08:45</option><option>09:00</option><option>09:15</option><option>09:30</option><option>09:45</option><option>10:00</option><option>10:15</option><option>10:30</option><option>10:45</option><option>11:00</option><option>11:15</option><option>11:30</option><option>11:45</option><option>12:00</option><option>12:15</option><option>12:30</option><option>12:45</option><option>13:00</option><option>13:15</option><option>13:30</option><option>13:45</option><option>14:00</option><option>14:15</option><option>14:30</option><option>14:45</option><option>15:00</option><option>15:15</option><option>15:30</option><option>15:45</option><option>16:00</option><option>16:15</option><option>16:30</option><option>16:45</option><option>17:00</option><option>17:15</option><option>17:30</option><option>17:45</option><option>18:00</option><option>18:15</option><option>18:30</option><option>18:45</option><option>19:00</option><option>19:15</option><option>19:30</option><option>19:45</option><option>20:00</option><option>20:15</option><option>20:30</option><option>20:45</option><option>21:00</option><option>21:15</option><option>21:30</option><option>21:45</option><option>22:00</option><option>22:15</option><option>22:30</option><option>22:45</option><option>23:00</option><option>23:15</option><option>23:30</option><option>23:45</option></select>
    </label>
    <label>Do
      <select name="timepicker" id="monday-to" class="timepicker"><option>00:00</option><option>00:15</option><option>00:30</option><option>00:45</option><option>01:00</option><option>01:15</option><option>01:30</option><option>01:45</option><option>02:00</option><option>02:15</option><option>02:30</option><option>02:45</option><option>03:00</option><option>03:15</option><option>03:30</option><option>03:45</option><option>04:00</option><option>04:15</option><option>04:30</option><option>04:45</option><option>05:00</option><option>05:15</option><option>05:30</option><option>05:45</option><option>06:00</option><option>06:15</option><option>06:30</option><option>06:45</option><option>07:00</option><option>07:15</option><option>07:30</option><option>07:45</option><option>08:00</option><option>08:15</option><option>08:30</option><option>08:45</option><option>09:00</option><option>09:15</option><option>09:30</option><option>09:45</option><option>10:00</option><option>10:15</option><option>10:30</option><option>10:45</option><option>11:00</option><option>11:15</option><option>11:30</option><option>11:45</option><option>12:00</option><option>12:15</option><option>12:30</option><option>12:45</option><option>13:00</option><option>13:15</option><option>13:30</option><option>13:45</option><option>14:00</option><option>14:15</option><option>14:30</option><option>14:45</option><option>15:00</option><option>15:15</option><option>15:30</option><option>15:45</option><option>16:00</option><option>16:15</option><option>16:30</option><option>16:45</option><option>17:00</option><option>17:15</option><option>17:30</option><option>17:45</option><option>18:00</option><option>18:15</option><option>18:30</option><option>18:45</option><option>19:00</option><option>19:15</option><option>19:30</option><option>19:45</option><option>20:00</option><option>20:15</option><option>20:30</option><option>20:45</option><option>21:00</option><option>21:15</option><option>21:30</option><option>21:45</option><option>22:00</option><option>22:15</option><option>22:30</option><option>22:45</option><option>23:00</option><option>23:15</option><option>23:30</option><option>23:45</option></select>
    </label>
    <label>Úterý
      <input class="toggle js-toggle" type="checkbox" id="tuesday-open" name="open">
    </label>
    <label>Od
      <select name="timepicker" id="tuesday-from" class="timepicker"><option>00:00</option><option>00:15</option><option>00:30</option><option>00:45</option><option>01:00</option><option>01:15</option><option>01:30</option><option>01:45</option><option>02:00</option><option>02:15</option><option>02:30</option><option>02:45</option><option>03:00</option><option>03:15</option><option>03:30</option><option>03:45</option><option>04:00</option><option>04:15</option><option>04:30</option><option>04:45</option><option>05:00</option><option>05:15</option><option>05:30</option><option>05:45</option><option>06:00</option><option>06:15</option><option>06:30</option><option>06:45</option><option>07:00</option><option>07:15</option><option>07:30</option><option>07:45</option><option>08:00</option><option>08:15</option><option>08:30</option><option>08:45</option><option>09:00</option><option>09:15</option><option>09:30</option><option>09:45</option><option>10:00</option><option>10:15</option><option>10:30</option><option>10:45</option><option>11:00</option><option>11:15</option><option>11:30</option><option>11:45</option><option>12:00</option><option>12:15</option><option>12:30</option><option>12:45</option><option>13:00</option><option>13:15</option><option>13:30</option><option>13:45</option><option>14:00</option><option>14:15</option><option>14:30</option><option>14:45</option><option>15:00</option><option>15:15</option><option>15:30</option><option>15:45</option><option>16:00</option><option>16:15</option><option>16:30</option><option>16:45</option><option>17:00</option><option>17:15</option><option>17:30</option><option>17:45</option><option>18:00</option><option>18:15</option><option>18:30</option><option>18:45</option><option>19:00</option><option>19:15</option><option>19:30</option><option>19:45</option><option>20:00</option><option>20:15</option><option>20:30</option><option>20:45</option><option>21:00</option><option>21:15</option><option>21:30</option><option>21:45</option><option>22:00</option><option>22:15</option><option>22:30</option><option>22:45</option><option>23:00</option><option>23:15</option><option>23:30</option><option>23:45</option></select>
    </label>
    <label>Do
      <select name="timepicker" id="tuesday-to" class="timepicker"><option>00:00</option><option>00:15</option><option>00:30</option><option>00:45</option><option>01:00</option><option>01:15</option><option>01:30</option><option>01:45</option><option>02:00</option><option>02:15</option><option>02:30</option><option>02:45</option><option>03:00</option><option>03:15</option><option>03:30</option><option>03:45</option><option>04:00</option><option>04:15</option><option>04:30</option><option>04:45</option><option>05:00</option><option>05:15</option><option>05:30</option><option>05:45</option><option>06:00</option><option>06:15</option><option>06:30</option><option>06:45</option><option>07:00</option><option>07:15</option><option>07:30</option><option>07:45</option><option>08:00</option><option>08:15</option><option>08:30</option><option>08:45</option><option>09:00</option><option>09:15</option><option>09:30</option><option>09:45</option><option>10:00</option><option>10:15</option><option>10:30</option><option>10:45</option><option>11:00</option><option>11:15</option><option>11:30</option><option>11:45</option><option>12:00</option><option>12:15</option><option>12:30</option><option>12:45</option><option>13:00</option><option>13:15</option><option>13:30</option><option>13:45</option><option>14:00</option><option>14:15</option><option>14:30</option><option>14:45</option><option>15:00</option><option>15:15</option><option>15:30</option><option>15:45</option><option>16:00</option><option>16:15</option><option>16:30</option><option>16:45</option><option>17:00</option><option>17:15</option><option>17:30</option><option>17:45</option><option>18:00</option><option>18:15</option><option>18:30</option><option>18:45</option><option>19:00</option><option>19:15</option><option>19:30</option><option>19:45</option><option>20:00</option><option>20:15</option><option>20:30</option><option>20:45</option><option>21:00</option><option>21:15</option><option>21:30</option><option>21:45</option><option>22:00</option><option>22:15</option><option>22:30</option><option>22:45</option><option>23:00</option><option>23:15</option><option>23:30</option><option>23:45</option></select>
    </label>
  </div>
</div>
```

[JS Fiddle demo](https://jsfiddle.net/davidThomas/y6wpzxr7/).

It's worth noting that I've included the times in the HTML, stripped out the repeated `class` attributes, removed the `for` attributes in the `<label>` since they all referred to the same `times` element (which wasn't present in the HTML) as it was both invalid, and unable to work. As the `<input>` and `<select>` elements are now wrapped within the `<label>` the association between the `<label>` and its nested element is implicit, and doesn't require the use of the `for` attribute; therefore it now works without having to assign `id` attributes to the various interactive form-elements.

Having just looked at your question again, I've realised that you seem to want your label-text to the left of the nested `<input>`, or `<select>` element; to that end the following two lines added to the CSS for the `<label>` element should satisfy that requirement:

```
label {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: space-between;
}
```

```css
*,
 ::before,
 ::after {
  box-sizing: border-box;
  font: normal 1rem / 1.5 sans-serif;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}

.opening-hours {
  font-size: 18px;
}

.opening-hours > div {
  display: grid;
  gap: 1em 0.5em;
  grid-template-columns: repeat(3, 1fr);
  margin: 1em auto;
  padding: 0.5em;
  width: clamp(30em, 900px, 90vw);
}

label {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: space-between;
  border: 1px solid #000;
  border-radius: 0.5em;
  padding: 0.5em;
}

:focus-visible {
  outline-width: 2px;
  outline-style: solid;
  outline-color: #f90;
  outline-offset: 0.1em;
}
```

```html
<div class="opening-hours">
  <div>
    <label for="monday-open">Pondělí
      <input type="checkbox" id="monday-open" name="open">
    </label>
    <label>Od
      <select name="timepicker" id="monday-from" class="timepicker"><option>00:00</option><option>00:15</option><option>00:30</option><option>00:45</option><option>01:00</option><option>01:15</option><option>01:30</option><option>01:45</option><option>02:00</option><option>02:15</option><option>02:30</option><option>02:45</option><option>03:00</option><option>03:15</option><option>03:30</option><option>03:45</option><option>04:00</option><option>04:15</option><option>04:30</option><option>04:45</option><option>05:00</option><option>05:15</option><option>05:30</option><option>05:45</option><option>06:00</option><option>06:15</option><option>06:30</option><option>06:45</option><option>07:00</option><option>07:15</option><option>07:30</option><option>07:45</option><option>08:00</option><option>08:15</option><option>08:30</option><option>08:45</option><option>09:00</option><option>09:15</option><option>09:30</option><option>09:45</option><option>10:00</option><option>10:15</option><option>10:30</option><option>10:45</option><option>11:00</option><option>11:15</option><option>11:30</option><option>11:45</option><option>12:00</option><option>12:15</option><option>12:30</option><option>12:45</option><option>13:00</option><option>13:15</option><option>13:30</option><option>13:45</option><option>14:00</option><option>14:15</option><option>14:30</option><option>14:45</option><option>15:00</option><option>15:15</option><option>15:30</option><option>15:45</option><option>16:00</option><option>16:15</option><option>16:30</option><option>16:45</option><option>17:00</option><option>17:15</option><option>17:30</option><option>17:45</option><option>18:00</option><option>18:15</option><option>18:30</option><option>18:45</option><option>19:00</option><option>19:15</option><option>19:30</option><option>19:45</option><option>20:00</option><option>20:15</option><option>20:30</option><option>20:45</option><option>21:00</option><option>21:15</option><option>21:30</option><option>21:45</option><option>22:00</option><option>22:15</option><option>22:30</option><option>22:45</option><option>23:00</option><option>23:15</option><option>23:30</option><option>23:45</option></select>
    </label>
    <label>Do
      <select name="timepicker" id="monday-to" class="timepicker"><option>00:00</option><option>00:15</option><option>00:30</option><option>00:45</option><option>01:00</option><option>01:15</option><option>01:30</option><option>01:45</option><option>02:00</option><option>02:15</option><option>02:30</option><option>02:45</option><option>03:00</option><option>03:15</option><option>03:30</option><option>03:45</option><option>04:00</option><option>04:15</option><option>04:30</option><option>04:45</option><option>05:00</option><option>05:15</option><option>05:30</option><option>05:45</option><option>06:00</option><option>06:15</option><option>06:30</option><option>06:45</option><option>07:00</option><option>07:15</option><option>07:30</option><option>07:45</option><option>08:00</option><option>08:15</option><option>08:30</option><option>08:45</option><option>09:00</option><option>09:15</option><option>09:30</option><option>09:45</option><option>10:00</option><option>10:15</option><option>10:30</option><option>10:45</option><option>11:00</option><option>11:15</option><option>11:30</option><option>11:45</option><option>12:00</option><option>12:15</option><option>12:30</option><option>12:45</option><option>13:00</option><option>13:15</option><option>13:30</option><option>13:45</option><option>14:00</option><option>14:15</option><option>14:30</option><option>14:45</option><option>15:00</option><option>15:15</option><option>15:30</option><option>15:45</option><option>16:00</option><option>16:15</option><option>16:30</option><option>16:45</option><option>17:00</option><option>17:15</option><option>17:30</option><option>17:45</option><option>18:00</option><option>18:15</option><option>18:30</option><option>18:45</option><option>19:00</option><option>19:15</option><option>19:30</option><option>19:45</option><option>20:00</option><option>20:15</option><option>20:30</option><option>20:45</option><option>21:00</option><option>21:15</option><option>21:30</option><option>21:45</option><option>22:00</option><option>22:15</option><option>22:30</option><option>22:45</option><option>23:00</option><option>23:15</option><option>23:30</option><option>23:45</option></select>
    </label>
    <label>Úterý
      <input class="toggle js-toggle" type="checkbox" id="tuesday-open" name="open">
    </label>
    <label>Od
      <select name="timepicker" id="tuesday-from" class="timepicker"><option>00:00</option><option>00:15</option><option>00:30</option><option>00:45</option><option>01:00</option><option>01:15</option><option>01:30</option><option>01:45</option><option>02:00</option><option>02:15</option><option>02:30</option><option>02:45</option><option>03:00</option><option>03:15</option><option>03:30</option><option>03:45</option><option>04:00</option><option>04:15</option><option>04:30</option><option>04:45</option><option>05:00</option><option>05:15</option><option>05:30</option><option>05:45</option><option>06:00</option><option>06:15</option><option>06:30</option><option>06:45</option><option>07:00</option><option>07:15</option><option>07:30</option><option>07:45</option><option>08:00</option><option>08:15</option><option>08:30</option><option>08:45</option><option>09:00</option><option>09:15</option><option>09:30</option><option>09:45</option><option>10:00</option><option>10:15</option><option>10:30</option><option>10:45</option><option>11:00</option><option>11:15</option><option>11:30</option><option>11:45</option><option>12:00</option><option>12:15</option><option>12:30</option><option>12:45</option><option>13:00</option><option>13:15</option><option>13:30</option><option>13:45</option><option>14:00</option><option>14:15</option><option>14:30</option><option>14:45</option><option>15:00</option><option>15:15</option><option>15:30</option><option>15:45</option><option>16:00</option><option>16:15</option><option>16:30</option><option>16:45</option><option>17:00</option><option>17:15</option><option>17:30</option><option>17:45</option><option>18:00</option><option>18:15</option><option>18:30</option><option>18:45</option><option>19:00</option><option>19:15</option><option>19:30</option><option>19:45</option><option>20:00</option><option>20:15</option><option>20:30</option><option>20:45</option><option>21:00</option><option>21:15</option><option>21:30</option><option>21:45</option><option>22:00</option><option>22:15</option><option>22:30</option><option>22:45</option><option>23:00</option><option>23:15</option><option>23:30</option><option>23:45</option></select>
    </label>
    <label>Do
      <select name="timepicker" id="tuesday-to" class="timepicker"><option>00:00</option><option>00:15</option><option>00:30</option><option>00:45</option><option>01:00</option><option>01:15</option><option>01:30</option><option>01:45</option><option>02:00</option><option>02:15</option><option>02:30</option><option>02:45</option><option>03:00</option><option>03:15</option><option>03:30</option><option>03:45</option><option>04:00</option><option>04:15</option><option>04:30</option><option>04:45</option><option>05:00</option><option>05:15</option><option>05:30</option><option>05:45</option><option>06:00</option><option>06:15</option><option>06:30</option><option>06:45</option><option>07:00</option><option>07:15</option><option>07:30</option><option>07:45</option><option>08:00</option><option>08:15</option><option>08:30</option><option>08:45</option><option>09:00</option><option>09:15</option><option>09:30</option><option>09:45</option><option>10:00</option><option>10:15</option><option>10:30</option><option>10:45</option><option>11:00</option><option>11:15</option><option>11:30</option><option>11:45</option><option>12:00</option><option>12:15</option><option>12:30</option><option>12:45</option><option>13:00</option><option>13:15</option><option>13:30</option><option>13:45</option><option>14:00</option><option>14:15</option><option>14:30</option><option>14:45</option><option>15:00</option><option>15:15</option><option>15:30</option><option>15:45</option><option>16:00</option><option>16:15</option><option>16:30</option><option>16:45</option><option>17:00</option><option>17:15</option><option>17:30</option><option>17:45</option><option>18:00</option><option>18:15</option><option>18:30</option><option>18:45</option><option>19:00</option><option>19:15</option><option>19:30</option><option>19:45</option><option>20:00</option><option>20:15</option><option>20:30</option><option>20:45</option><option>21:00</option><option>21:15</option><option>21:30</option><option>21:45</option><option>22:00</option><option>22:15</option><option>22:30</option><option>22:45</option><option>23:00</option><option>23:15</option><option>23:30</option><option>23:45</option></select>
    </label>
  </div>
</div>
```

[JS Fiddle demo](https://jsfiddle.net/davidThomas/y6wpzxr7/).

References:

- [`clamp()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/clamp).
- [`display`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/display).
- [`:focus-visible`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/:focus-visible).
- [`gap`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/gap).
- [`justify-content`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/justify-content).
- [`outline`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/outline).
- [`repeat()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/repeat).

Bibliography:

- "[A Complete Guide to Flexbox](https://css-tricks.com/snippets/css/a-guide-to-flexbox/)," (CSS-Tricks).
- "[A Complete Guide to Grid](https://css-tricks.com/snippets/css/complete-guide-grid/)," (CSS-Tricks).
- "[Basic concepts of flexbox](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/CSS_Flexible_Box_Layout/Basic_Concepts_of_Flexbox)," (MDN).
- "[CSS Grid Layout](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/CSS_Grid_Layout)," (Mozilla Developer Network).

Comment: Thanks for your advice and i keep that in my mind. :)

Comment: You're very welcome indeed, I'm glad to have helped. Incidentally, I did - finally - realise that you wanted the label-text to the left of your `<input>` elements; so I've added a second demo and code to show how that might be achieved.

Answer (score 2):

Firstly understand what's messing up the alignment; it's majorly caused by the variable width of the label. One very basic solution without using complicated CSS properties would be simply giving this label tag a fixed width.

```css
label {
  display: inline-block;
  width: 50px;
  font-size: 18px;
  margin: 0 10px;
}
```

```html
<div class="opening-hours">
  <div>
    <label class="label-container">Pondělí</label>
    <input class="toggle" type="checkbox" id="monday-open" name="open" class="js-toggle" />
    <label for="times">Od</label>
    <select name="timepicker" id="monday-from" class="timepicker"></select>
    <label for="times">Do</label>
    <select name="timepicker" id="monday-from" class="timepicker"></select>
  </div>
  <div>
    <label>Úterý</label>
    <input class="toggle" type="checkbox" id="tuesday-open" name="open" class="js-toggle" />
    <label for="times">Od</label>
    <select name="timepicker" id="tuesday-from" class="timepicker"></select>
    <label for="times">Do</label>
    <select name="timepicker" id="tuesday-to" class="timepicker"></select>
  </div>
</div>
```

Note: Avoid using inline CSS if you have to repeat the same styling on multiple tags. Instead, try using classes.

Answer (score 1):

First and foremost, remove all your inline margins set. Then you can go to your CSS file and set `display: flex;` on your parent `opening-hoenter`. I would set this flex-direction to `column`. Then you can flex each child div with a `row` flex-direction and set a gap of 15px. This ensures that each row is aligned with the same spacing. Now you can set an inline margin on div #2 to align the two vertically. I set `margin-left: .9rem;` on the second `div`.

```css
.opening-hoenter {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
}

.opening-hoenter > div {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: row;
  gap: 15px;
}
```

```html
<div class="opening-hoenter image description hereurs">
  <div>
    <label style="font-size: 18px;">Pondělí</label>
    <input class="toggle" type="checkbox" id="monday-open" name="open" class="js-toggle" />
    <label for="times" style="font-size: 18px;">Od</label>
    <select name="timepicker" id="monday-from" class="timepicker"></select>
    <label for="times" style="font-size: 18px;">Do</label>
    <select name="timepicker" id="monday-from" class="timepicker"></select>
  </div>

  <div style="margin-left: .9rem;">
    <label style="font-size: 18px;">Úterý</label>
    <input class="toggle" type="checkbox" id="tuesday-open" name="open" class="js-toggle" />
    <label for="times" style="font-size: 18px;">Od</label>
    <select name="timepicker" id="tuesday-from" class="timepicker"></select>
    <label for="times" style="font-size: 18px;">Do</label>
    <select name="timepicker" id="tuesday-to" class="timepicker"></select>
  </div>
</div>
```

Another option would be to use this same layout but instead of the inline-margin on div #2 you can set your label to have the same width universally so that all elements after that are aligned because the label will have a dynamic width that is set at let's say `10%`. You can set an `id` on that label to define this. In this ex. I called it `#fixed-label`

See that version here.

```css
.opening-hoenter {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
}

.opening-hoenter > div {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: row;
  gap: 15px;
}

label#fixed-label {
  width: 10%;
}
```

```html
<div class="opening-hoenter image description hereurs">
  <div>
    <label style="font-size: 18px;" id="fixed-label">Pondělí</label>
    <input class="toggle" type="checkbox" id="monday-open" name="open" class="js-toggle" />
    <label for="times" style="font-size: 18px;">Od</label>
    <select name="timepicker" id="monday-from" class="timepicker"></select>
    <label for="times" style="font-size: 18px;">Do</label>
    <select name="timepicker" id="monday-from" class="timepicker"></select>
  </div>

  <div>
    <label style="font-size: 18px;" id="fixed-label">Úterý</label>
    <input class="toggle" type="checkbox" id="tuesday-open" name="open" class="js-toggle" />
    <label for="times" style="font-size: 18px;">Od</label>
    <select name="timepicker" id="tuesday-from" class="timepicker"></select>
    <label for="times" style="font-size: 18px;">Do</label>
    <select name="timepicker" id="tuesday-to" class="timepicker"></select>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Thanks! Thats exactly what i am looking for!

Answer (score 0):

you can find help on https://www.w3schools.com/html/default.asp. You just have to take a look

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).